# JDK-1.8 missing 'server' JVM at JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, java-8

I have a Linux Centos 7 server with Java 1.7.

```
   Static hostname: primary.abc.co
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 3aec2b029e5b43d392206467af5984ac
           Boot ID: 9aaa701be84147669f1dcce3243168b4
    Virtualization: vmware
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

It has many apps, which I want to upgrade one of them to use Java1.8. So I download JDK-1.8 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) (jdk-8u261-linux-i586.tar.gz).

I create a script (build.sh) to do the maven build with Java1.8 because the JAVA_HOME is Java1.7 for all the other apps.

**build-osgi.sh**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_261/
echo $JAVA_HOME
mvn -V clean install -DskipTests
```

Error:

> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_261/
>
> Error: missing 'server' JVM at
> `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_261/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so'. Please install
> or use the JRE or JDK that contains these missing components.

So when the `-V` (java version) gets executed, it gives the error, suggesting that the JDK has missing components.

**Question**

Does anyone know where I can get a JDK1.8 that will work? (I thought from the Oracle site would work).  Or is there something else I should do?

Comment: Was there a reason you did not use the openjdk 8 included with centos 7? Packagename: java-1.8.0-openjdk - Also: The one you downloaded is the 32 bit java, but you really should download the 64bit version from oracle if you can't use the openjdk from centos.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a different version of JDK 8 and it works.  (x64 instead of x86)

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

```
jdk-8u261-linux-x64.tar.gz
```